# dompdf table rendering issue

Tags: php, pdf, optimization, dompdf

I'm using DomPDF to generate invoices in a project I'm working on.
I've done so several times before and never had any trouble but since today however It got so slow that the maximum execution time gets reached.
I've confirmed that this happens because of: `$dompdf->render()`
I'm generating some tables to display the data in. but is seems to find this table quite difficult. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

dompdf and my table can be found: http://pastebin.com/G585VQma
(figured I'd put it on pastebin to save some space)

Answer (score 0):

dompdf doesn't support splitting table cells through pages, so you need to change the tables with `cellspacing="10"` into block elements like `div`s with the same styling, or at least not put the tables with many lines inside of these tables.