# Generation issue in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm using DomPDF to generate certificate in a project I'm working on.
I've done so several times before and never had any trouble but since today however It got so slow that the maximum execution time gets reached.
I've confirmed that this happens because of: `$dompdf->render()`
I'm generating some tables to display the data in. but is seems to find this table quite difficult. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but we have given up on using dompdf. We now use wkhtmltopdf (free but a bit buggy) or docraptor (an excellent commercial service)

Comment: possible duplicate of [dompdf table rendering issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634825/dompdf-table-rendering-issue)

Comment: almost word-for-word duplicate

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are trying to use styling for elements or selectors that are above CSS 2.1 (which dompdf currently supports). You can check this [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility) to verify if the table styling is supported.

Also be careful when using third party libraries such as Bootstrap, as they tend to require CSS support greater than CSS 2.1 (which is supported by dompdf).